# camel cxfrs put with path param overrides payload

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I develop a rest endpoint in camel and would like to provide the following PUT - Method /service/createObject/{objectId} which also accepts a payload.

If I configure a mehtod like this, the payload will be overridden with the path parameter {objectId}. Is that the default behaviour and can I change it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate and also show us your implementation? It's not fully clear what you mean by the payload being overloaded by the path param.

Comment: I solved the problem by using a resource class with simple binding. https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-cxf/src/main/docs/cxfrs-component.adoc#consuming-a-rest-request---simple-binding-style